# Rails Google Client API - unable to exchange a refresh token for access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth, access-token, google-api-client

After struggling with some [SSL issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520314/ssl-error-in-rails-3-2-3-while-using-google-oauth2-client-to-access-api) on my machine, I'm still trying to access a user's Blogger account through the Google Ruby Client API.  I'm using the following:

- Rails 3.2.3
- Ruby 1.9.3
- oauth2 (0.8.0)
- omniauth (1.1.1)
- omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.1.13)
- google-api-client (0.4.6)

I can successfully authenticate users and access their blogs through the Google API at the time of authentication. When a user logs in, I store the `access_token` and `refresh_token` I receive from Google. and everything works great until the `access_token` expires.  I'm trying to build the functionality that exchanges the `refresh_token` for a new `access_token`, but keep coming up against walls.  Using the [client documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/OAuth2) as an example, this is the code I'm using:

```
  client = Google::APIClient.new
  token_pair = auth.oauth_token   # access_token and refresh_token received during authentication

  # Load the access token if it's available
  if token_pair  
    client.authorization.update_token!(token_pair.to_hash)
  end            

  # Update access token if expired
  if client.authorization.refresh_token && client.authorization.expired?
    client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
  end

  blogger = client.discovered_api('blogger', 'v3')
  result = client.execute(
      api_method: blogger.blogs.list_by_user,
      parameters: {'userId' => "self", 'fields' => 'items(description,id,name,url)'},
      headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

This code works perfectly while the `access_token` is valid.  As soon as it expires though, I'm seeing 2 problems:

1. Even though I know the token is expired (I've checked `expires_at` value in the database), `client.authorization.expired?` returns `false` -- is there a different way I can check the expiration of the token besides using the value in the database?
2. When I force the execution of `client.authorization.fetch_access_token!` I get an `invalid_request` error.

Can someone please let me know how I can exchange a `refresh_token` for a new `access_token` using the client API?  Even if you know how to do it in another language, that would be a big help as I can then try to Rubyfy it.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may have already found this, but you can read through the whole process here at google: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

The omniauth-google-oauth2 strategy already takes care of setting the access_type and approval_prompt so getting a refresh token is just a matter of posting to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token with grant_type=request_token

Here is *roughly* the code I use:

```
def refresh_token
  data = {
    :client_id => GOOGLE_KEY,
    :client_secret => GOOGLE_SECRET,
    :refresh_token => REFRESH_TOKEN,
    :grant_type => "refresh_token"
  }
  @response = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(RestClient.post "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", data)
  if @response["access_token"].present?
    # Save your token
  else
    # No Token
  end
rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
  # Bad request
rescue
  # Something else bad happened
end
```

Comment: brimil01, you are the man!! I don't even know why this works and my other attempts at making HTTP calls didn't, but I've been looking at this for 12 hours, so I'll figure it out tomorrow.  Your code totally works and you've saved me from massive head-banging, so much appreciated.

Comment: I seem to get this when I post this: 

#<HTTParty::Response:0x7fa516a926e0 parsed_response={"error"=>"invalid_request"}, @response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>, @headers={"cache-control"=>["no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"], "pragma"=>["no-cache"], "expires"=>["Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"], "date"=>["Wed, 27 Mar 2013 08:50:48 GMT"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"], "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"], "server"=>["GSE"], "connection"=>["close"]}>...

Answer (score 16):

Since you are using the Ruby Google API Client, why not use it to exchange the refresh token as well? The Ruby API does pretty much the same thing internally, which @brimil01 has said in his answer.

This is how I use the Ruby API to exchange my refresh token for a new access token.

```
def self.exchange_refresh_token( refresh_token )
  client = Google::APIClient.new
  client.authorization.client_id = CLIENT_ID
  client.authorization.client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
  client.authorization.grant_type = 'refresh_token'
  client.authorization.refresh_token = refresh_token

  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
  client.authorization
end
```

And according to [this issue here](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/4), it is recommended not to use the `expired?` method to check if an access token has expired.

> Basically, don't call the expired? method. There are essentially zero
>   scenarios where that's a good idea. It simply won't give you reliable
>   expiration information. It's more of a hint than a real expiration
>   timestamp, and the token server may decide to honor an expired token
>   anyways in certain somewhat theoretical, but important, circumstances.
>   If you do get an invalid grant error, always refresh your access token
>   and retry once. If you're still getting an error, raise the error.

Here is what I do.

```
# Retrieved stored credentials for the provided user email address.
#
# @param [String] email_address
#   User's email address.
# @return [Signet::OAuth2::Client]
#  Stored OAuth 2.0 credentials if found, nil otherwise.
def self.get_stored_credentials(email_address)
  hash = Thread.current['google_access_token']
  return nil if hash.blank?

  hash[email_address]
end

##
# Store OAuth 2.0 credentials in the application's database.
#
# @param [String] user_id
#   User's ID.
# @param [Signet::OAuth2::Client] credentials
#   OAuth 2.0 credentials to store.
def self.store_credentials(email_address, credentials)
  Thread.current['google_access_token'] ||= {}
  Thread.current['google_access_token'][email_address] = credentials
end


def self.credentials_expired?( credentials )
  client = Google::APIClient.new
  client.authorization = credentials
  oauth2 = client.discovered_api('oauth2', 'v2')
  result = client.execute!(:api_method => oauth2.userinfo.get)

  (result.status != 200)
end


# @return [Signet::OAuth2::Client]
#  OAuth 2.0 credentials containing an access and refresh token.
def self.get_credentials
  email_address = ''

  # Check if a valid access_token is already available.
  credentials = get_stored_credentials( email_address )
  # If not available, exchange the refresh_token to obtain a new access_token.

  if credentials.blank?
    credentials = exchange_refresh_token(REFRESH_TOKEN)
    store_credentials(email_address, credentials)
  else
    are_credentials_expired = credentials_expired?(credentials)

    if are_credentials_expired
      credentials = exchange_refresh_token(REFRESH_TOKEN)
      store_credentials(email_address, credentials)
    end
  end

  credentials
end
```

Comment: In `credentials_expired?`, the call to `client.execute` shouldn't use the `execute!` form, since it will raise an exception if credentials are expired instead of populating `result` with the unauthorized status.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with simple code below.

```
   def refesh_auth_tooken(refresh_token) 
       client = Google::APIClient.new 
       puts "REFESH TOOKEN"
       client.authorization = client_secrets
       client.authorization.refresh_token = refresh_token

       #puts YAML::dump(client.authorization)

       client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
       return client.authorization

     end
```